# Close main form when other form open

Tags: vb.net, forms, hide

How can i hide main form and open the second one.

```
      If My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\tFull", "tFull", Nothing) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Show()
    Else
        FrmPocetak.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End If
```

It won't close the main form but it opens the FrmPocetak :( :(

Comment: Visual studio in vb.net (not C#) will always show the main form after load. Try the visible property instead, possibly minimize it.

Comment: I set in project properties ShutDown mode when all forms close and i was able to fix with Me.Close()